# Ho to make btrfs snapshot in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.10, btrfs, snapshot

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 with the `/` partition as btrfs, I want to make a snapshot of the subvolume  `/home` occasionally. How to I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help ya out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs part of which is shown below.
hope i was helpful and best luck to ya :D

#### How to work with snaphots in Ubuntu's layout

In order to work with snapshots of **/** or **/home** in the Ubuntu layout it is very convenient to mount the btrfs filesystem at a separate location, and work from the top of the btrfs tree, rather than from the mounted subvolumes.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX# /mnt
```

**Create snapshots**

To create a snapshot use:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/@ /mnt/@_snapshot
```

This will create a snapshot of the **@** subvolume named **@_snapshot** located also in the top of the btrfs tree.

**Rollback to a snapshot**

To roll back to a snapshot, you simply need to change its name to the name that Ubuntu mounts, using:

```
sudo mv /mnt/@ /mnt/@_badroot
sudo mv /mnt/@_snapshot /mnt/@
```

and reboot.

**Delete a snapshot**

To delete a snapshot use:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/@_badroot
```

btrfs snapshots are subvolumes in themselves, and self-contained, deleting the old **@** subvolume like this is fine, provided we have a replacement.

Comment: How come I can't delete a snapshot with  rm -rf?